# Need a Context in a non-Activity class

Tags: android

There are a lot of questions asking how to popup a toast from another class, I must have tried all of them and none appear to work.

I am extending the webViewClient and need to popup some messages related to loading errors etc with toast, however I appear to be unable to define the context ?

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private static Context context;
    public MyAppWebViewClient(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public static void popup(String message){
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    popup("Hello World")
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Error:(301, 34) error: constructor MyAppWebViewClient in class MyAppWebViewClient cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: What line of code causes the error?

Comment: @Blackbelt - thanks for helping, I did as you suggested and added super(); as the first line but the error is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `context` variable should not be `static`. Your code will probably work with the `static` modifier. However it is used incorrectly.

Next, the `MyAppWebViewClient` constructor requires a `Context` parameter, so you must provide one when creating `MyAppWebViewClient` instances. For example:

```
WebViewClient client = new MyAppWebViewClient(this);
```

I assume this line of code is inside a method of a subclass of `Activity`. If you are in a `Fragment` subclass instead then do this:

```
WebViewClient client = new MyAppWebViewClient(getActivity());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you can probably tell that I'm no expert, the solution was to pass the context from the main class, I learnt something today :-)